# How to make bluetooth earphones recording sound level independent on output sound level?

Tags: debian, pulseaudio, obs-studio

I use Debian 11, Xfce4 and if I use laptop speakers I can set 1% volume and on OBS Studio (or Pulseaudio Output devices) there will be the same recording sound level as if I'd set 80%. The same with jack earphones. However, when I use bluetooth earphones, recording volume is dependent on Output volume, so if I set it to less than 20%, I can't hear it in OBS Studio recording. Can I somehow make bt earphones recording sound level independent on output volume? One of workarounds I was thinking about is to make both speakers and earphones play simultaneously and set speaker volume to 1% but I couldn't achieve this on my laptop. Thanks.